# Where is Ringtone folder in device(DDMS)

Tags: android, android-studio

I try to see the ringtones files with the DDMS i cant see it. Someone know the specific path?

Where is the ringtone folder?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is mnt/sdcard/Ringtones/ /sdcard/media/Ringtones/ .It mignt be on external SDCard as well, In such cases path will be /extSdCard/Ringtones